# Accessing rule return values from contexts

Tags: antlr4

I'm using [this](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/code/actions/CSV.g4) example code to better understand ANTLR. From what I understand the `row` rule returns a `Map<String,String> values`. The `rows` label inside the `file` rule collects all the RowContext objects. From the for-each loop in the `file` rule, is there a way to access the `Map<String,String> values` returned by the `row` rule?

If not, how can I achieve accessing all of the `row` rules' `Map<String,String> values` from the `file` rule?

Snippet of the code:

```
/** Derived from rule "file : hdr row+ ;" */
file
locals [int i=0]
     : hdr ( rows+=row[$hdr.text.split(",")] {$i++;} )+
       {
       System.out.println($i+" rows");
       for (RowContext r : $rows) {
           System.out.println("row token interval: "+r.getSourceInterval());
       }
       }
     ;

hdr : row[null] {System.out.println("header: '"+$text.trim()+"'");} ;

/** Derived from rule "row : field (',' field)* '\r'? '\n' ;" */
row[String[] columns] returns [Map<String,String> values]
locals [int col=0]
@init {
    $values = new HashMap<String,String>();
}
@after {
    if ($values!=null && $values.size()>0) {
        System.out.println("values = "+$values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the generated `CSVParser.java`. You can find your inline code in this generated file. If you want to access the values, just access the field `values` of `RowContext`.

```
for (RowContext r : $rows) {
  System.out.println("row token interval: "+r.getSourceInterval());
  System.out.println("values: "+r.values);
}
```

However I recommend not to use inline code in a parser grammar. ANTLR generates a `Visitor` and a `Listener` for you. Listener/Visitor-Code is compiled just in time (if you use an appropriate IDE) while generator inline code is not compiled until generation time.